# aws cloutfront static site with api gateways in multiple regions with route53 geo latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I need to be multiple regions.

I have these two api gateways:

```
https://bqifffff7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/api/register
https://vqffff.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/production/api/register
```

My static site is hosted on cloudfront:

```
www.example.com
```

In route 53 I would do geo latency

How do I invoke so the following is called with geo latency?

```
www.example.com/api/register
```

Comment: You cannot use Route 53 to handle the path portion of a domain name. Only the domain name itself.

Comment: @JohnHanley the site is hosted on CloudFront, which means each path pattern points to an origin hostname that you specify (with CloudFront reverse-proxying requests for that path to the specified host).  This, in turn, means you *can* handle it with Route 53 latency based routing (based on the location of the CloudFront edge that resolves the origin hostname after matching the path pattern).  Unfortunately, this is where you hit an unrelated limitation: you can't configure API Gateway to expect the same hostname in multiple regions, which this setup requires.

Comment: @Tampa you've bumped into a limitation of API Gateway for which you're going to need a workaround.  One possibility involves Lambda@Edge, but this means we will either need to so some HTTP redirects or requests will be subject to a timeout of 3 seconds, neither of which may be viable.  What methods does your API use?  Is it only `GET` or does it use `POST` or other methods?

Comment: This isn't a limitation in API Gateway anymore. Now you can create Regional Domain Names in two or more API Gateway regions for the same domain name and then use R53 latency-based routing to alias to the regional endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a limitation in API Gateway anymore. Now you can create Regional Domain Names in two or more API Gateway regions for the same domain name and then use R53 latency-based routing to alias to the regional endpoints. For more details, see https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-regional-api-endpoints/